# covert column values into row names in sql server

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table, for-xml-path

I have this table structure

```
PRN               studentName       moduleName     theoryMarks 

180841220008       Mahendra          A              12             
180841220009       Mahendra1         A              13              
180841220008       Mahendra          B              12             
180841220009       Mahendra1         B              13
```

I want to show the result in below format

```
PRN               studentName      moduleName A     moduleName B 
180841220008      Mahendra         12                12
180841220009      Mahendra1        13                13
```

how to do this? I want to create a result generation system and show data to the user

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: why are you written for-xml-path, what's though for this tag?

Comment: @Phong I have tried dynamic pivot table

Comment: Show us your attempt, please. What's the actual result and your issue?

Comment: SELECT PRN,studentName,theoryMarks,Advanced Web Programming,Advanced Software Development Methodologies FROM
 (
  SELECT PRN, studentName, theoryMarks,moduleName FROM ModuleWiseLabTheoryMarks
  )  orgData
 PIVOT
 (
  sum(theoryMarks)
  FOR Color IN  (Advanced Web Programming,Advanced Software Development Methodologies)
 ) pvt     this query  shows error at  orgdata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot table dynamic` like below

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';


 SELECT PRN, studentName, moduleName,theoryMarks, Col = 'moduleName ' + moduleName
 into #b
 FROM #a

SELECT @columns += QUOTENAME(Col) + ','
from (SELECT DISTINCT Col FROM #b) A

-- remove the last comma
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);


SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ( SELECT PRN, studentName, theoryMarks, Col FROM  #b) src PIVOT( MAX([theoryMarks]) FOR Col IN ('+ @columns +')) AS pivot_table;';

-- execute the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

[**Result here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0577dfbd51d632ac0362c42dfdf8b75f)

[image]

Comment: @Phonge Your answer is perfect solution for my problem

Answer (score 4):

Please check this

```
Declare  @yt TABLE(  [PRN] bigint, studentName  varchar(500),   moduleName       varchar(500),theoryMarks   varchar(500) );

INSERT INTO @yt (  [PRN], studentName, moduleName, theoryMarks )
VALUES     (180841220008, 'Mahendra','A', 12),
(180841220009, 'Mahendra1','A', 13),
(180841220008, 'Mahendra','B', 12),
(180841220009, 'Mahendra1','B', 13)
select [PRN], studentName, moduleName, theoryMarks   from @yt
select [PRN], studentName, [A] [moduleName A],[B] [moduleName B]from (  select [PRN], studentName, moduleName, theoryMarks   from @yt ) src
pivot
(
  max(theoryMarks)
  for 
  moduleName in ([A], [B])
) piv;
```

Output will be:

[image]

If you want a dynamic query for the result, check this with 'For XML Path'

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef97e15e48b531dfae538c6bcdf813eb
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1578790046398e64f5ac7ea091d324a5

```
create table temp(  [PRN] bigint, studentName  varchar(500),   moduleName       varchar(500),theoryMarks   varchar(500) );

INSERT INTO temp (  [PRN], studentName, moduleName, theoryMarks )
VALUES     (180841220008, 'Mahendra','A', 12),
(180841220009, 'Mahendra1','A', 13),
(180841220008, 'Mahendra','B', 12),
(180841220009, 'Mahendra1','B', 13)

select [PRN], studentName, moduleName, theoryMarks   from temp

-----

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.moduleName) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [PRN], studentName, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select [PRN], studentName, moduleName, theoryMarks
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(theoryMarks)
                for moduleName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p'

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Note that this solution is not a dynamic situation `moduleName A, moduleName B, moduleName C, ect.`

Comment: @Ajay2707 how can add serial  number in this result

Comment: @Ajay2707 how to add serial number to result in your solution if i add ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PRN asc) AS SrNo, in' query' it generates unexpected result

Comment: @Ajay2707   it does not allow to use order by in  sub query unless i use top in query